# How to manage high traffic on news portal(cache)?

Tags: php, cache

I have some questions regarding to my news portal, where I have some issues with high traffic.

**The issues is**: I have daily about 50 k UU, and sometimes I have shots about 20 k UU in one time from socials links. In this case my server is going down due to RAM overload due to number of request to database, and some process in apache is hanging.

I'm looking for some advice what to do, to handle it. My ideas: 
1) Simply buy more powerfull server(I will do it)
2) Using proper caching. I'm not sure how to use it in proper way, because I have news portal, so it's always very important how fast users will see new post. Could you give me any adivce ?

Specs of my server: 
I'm using wiredtree with SSD 2000: 2,5 GB RAM, storage: 50GB Pure SSD RAID-10, CPU PRIORITY x2, Bandwith 6TB.

**EDIT:**

More about cache - I don't fully get how should I do it, because it's very important to me, to display new news to users very quickly. And the issue is when I have shot of 20 k UU in one time, and all will start reading it directly from DB, it will overload RAM due to too many request to DB.

Comment: @Daniel the most important for me is part about cache :)

Comment: your question will not garner any meaningful answers beyond "there's always a bigger mouse trap" - perhaps rephrase it to detail what is actually happening now.